# Проблема Шифр Цезаря Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Суть задачи такова :
Ваша миссия - зашифровать текст сообщения (в исходных данных не будет специальных символов вроде "!", "&", "?", только текст и пробелы) используя шифр Цезаря где каждая буква исходного текста заменяется другой, которая находится на определенном расстоянии в алфавите. Например, ("a b c", 3) == "d e f"

функция вызывается в таком виде:

```
to_encrypt("important text", 10)
```

где первый аргумент это текст ,а второй это число которое нужно прибавить к начальному символу , чтобы получить новый символ

Вот мой код:

```
def to_encrypt(text, delta):
    import string
    alpha = string.ascii_letters
    text = list(text)
    for c in text:
        text[text.index(c)] = alpha[alpha.index(c) + delta].lower() if c != ' ' else ' '   
    return "".join(text).lower()
```

Но проблема в том что при подаче текста "important text", происходит нужная замена всех букв кроме одной:

```
Результат который должен быть : "swzybdkhd dohd"
Результат который выходит у меня : "swzybdkhd doxd"
```

Замена предпоследней буквы не происходит.
Прошу помощи в обнаружении причин этой проблемы

Comment: Вам нужно зациклить алфавит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя идти по списку и одновременно изменять его, потому что при каждой итерации на входе будут уже другие данные (технически можно, конечно, но потом замучаешься выискивать ошибки, которые могут еще и проявиться в самый неожиданный момент). Нужно создавать новый список:

```
def to_encrypt(text, delta):
    import string
    alpha = string.ascii_letters
    # новый (пока что пустой) список для результата
    new_text = [] 
    for c in text:
        # присоединяем по буковке
        new_text.append(alpha[alpha.index(c) + delta].lower() if c != ' ' else ' ')
    # возвращаем из функции зашифрованную строчку
    return "".join(new_text).lower()
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь и совет , буду держать это в голове

Comment: Ой, только не надо советовать "собирать" текст с помощью `append` !!!

Comment: @AlexTitov Ой, никто и не советует.

Answer (score 1):

```
import string
delta = 10  # abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz -> klmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghij
lower = (string.ascii_lowercase[delta:] + string.ascii_lowercase[:delta])
translate = {ord(a): d for (a, d) in zip(string.ascii_letters, (lower + lower.upper()))}
result = str.translate("important text", translate)
```