# Шифр цезаря,не выводит шифр полностью,только первую букву

Tags: python

```
    #Шифр цезаря
SYMBOLS = 'АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя 1234567890!@#$%^&*()'
MAX_KEY_SIZE = len(SYMBOLS)
def getMode():
    while True:
        print('Вы хотите зашифровать,расшифровать или взломать текст?')
        mode = input().lower()
        if mode in ['зашифровать','з','расшифровать','р','взломать','в']:
            return mode
        else:
            print("Введите 'зашифровать' или 'з'для зашифровки или 'расшифровать' или 'р' для зашифровки,или 'взломать'или 'в' для взлома")
def getMessage():
    print('Введите текст:')
    return input()
def getKey():
    key = 0
    while True:
        print('Введите ключ шифрования(1-%s)' %(MAX_KEY_SIZE))
        key = int(input())

        if (key>=1 and key <=MAX_KEY_SIZE):
            return key

def getTranslatedMessage(mode,message,key):
    if mode[0] == 'р':
        key = -key
    translated = ''

    for symbol in message:
        symbolIndex = SYMBOLS.find(symbol)
        if symbolIndex == -1:#Символ не найден в SYMBOLS.
            #Просто добавить этот символ без именений.
            translated += symbol
        else:
            #Зашифровать или расшифровать
            symbolIndex += key
            if symbolIndex >=len(SYMBOLS):
                symbolIndex -= len (SYMBOLS)
            elif symbolIndex < 0:
                symbolIndex += len(SYMBOLS)

            translated += SYMBOLS[symbolIndex]
            return translated

mode = getMode()
message = getMessage()
if mode[0]!='в':
    key = getKey()
    print('Преобразованный текст:')
else:
    for key in range(1,MAX_KEY_SIZE + 1):
        print(key,getTranslatedMessage('расшифровать',message,key))
```

Comment: Вопрос про [шифр цезаря](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594690/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80-%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F-python?rq=1) Возможно, он как то вам поможет. И [еще один](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/857744/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80-%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F-python?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сместить влево return translated на один уровень с for